# What am I missing? ST7735 TFT white screen

Tags: arduino-uno, display, wires, tft

I followed this guy's [guide](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-displays/1-8tft-v1-0-st7736-arduino-tutorial-1-hello-world/) with regards to wiring, etc., and all I seem to be getting is a white screen, as shown in these [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjc9C.jpg). Is there an issue with the guy's guide, I'm missing or there is an issue with my wiring (pictures also included in above link) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the issue may well be that you haven't connected VCC and GND on the display to anything

Comment: The guide i was following suggested that "Connecting to VCC and ground like you’re accustomed to doing just won’t work here." ... that is not the case?

Comment: read comments in that guide

Comment: Oh look at that, "Thank you,
This worked for me only if I connected the VCC and Ground as well" and it indeed made it work. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: TFT utterly temperamental anyway, i guess that's what you get for paying not much for it.